# Retrieve a record from table with particular datetime

Tags: sql-server, date, jpa, select, where-clause

I need to retrieve a record with specific DateTime in SQL Server. Tried with many options like

```
select *
from test
where convert(datetime ,imported_date) = convert(datetime,'2020-06-16 
22:00:07')
```

imported_date is of datetime2 datatype.
Less than and Greater than is working but equals condition is failing. Please help

Comment: datetime2 is more precise than datetime. So what is the exact value of the column `imported_date` in the row you are attempting to select? You might be running into this [datetime to datetime2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/de5dbf3e-8c95-40f4-9e31-b71f1f31983d/change-in-datetime2-implementation-in-sql-server-2016?forum=transactsql) conversion issue. Edit: it really stinks that MS broke all their connect links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, your datetime has fractional seconds. If so, I would recommend phrasing this as:

```
where 
    imported_date >= '2020-06-16 22:00:07' 
    and imported_date < '2020-06-16 22:00:08'
```

This is much more efficient than using conversion functions on the datetime column, since it allows the database to make use of an index on that column, if any.

If you are working with a parameter:

```
where 
    imported_date >= @param_date
    and imported_date < dateadd(second, 1, @param_date)
```